# Bayesian Reliability

Tags: statistics

New rockets were launched by ISRO. Out of the total 11 launches, 3 were success and 8 were failures. Specify a statistical model to be used for predicting launch outcome or future success of the new rocket systems.

Answer (score 0):

the likelihood is the following

$$p(\mathbf{x}|\theta)\propto \theta^3(1-\theta)^8$$

which is a Binomial model

What does it suggest to you?

Comment: Why likelihood function is used here?